# PuTTY logging file date time

Tags: files, logs, putty

I use Putty on my job and capture the output with the logging option. What I need to do is have a date and time appended to each line. Is there any way to capture the live PuTTY output and append the date time to each line.

Many Thanks,
Bob (RtR)
'Go Navy - Beat Army'
Many thanks to ALL our Veterans . .

Comment: research `putty timestamp`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to capture the time of? Commands you have run? Output from commands you have run? Both?

Answer (score 1):

The PuTTY website has [this marked](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/log-timestamp.html) as a request for enhancement made back in 2017.  Does not appear anything has been done.

However, there is a slightly messy way to make this happen.  First, setup PuTTY to log to a file, (example uses `/path/to/log/putty/log`).  Make sure PuTTY is setup to with "Flush log file frequently" checked in the logging options.

In a `bash` terminal window, use `tail` to follow the log file and pipe that to `ts` (timestamp).  Something like this:

```bash
tail -f /path/to/log/putty/log &> >( ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] ' ) \
  | tee /path/to/timestamped/log
```

Using `tee` is optional if you don't care to see the output.  Output is something like this:

```
[2023-08-01 21:29:19]  user@pi:~ $ uname -a
Linux web-pi 5.10.103-v8+ #1529 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 8 12:26:46 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
[2023-08-01 21:29:31]  user@pi:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
[2023-08-01 21:29:31]  Distributor ID:Raspbian
[2023-08-01 21:29:31]  Description:Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
[2023-08-01 21:29:31]  Release:11
[2023-08-01 21:29:31]  Codename:bullseye
```